# Using an old trained model on a new data - comparing two populations

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank, quality-control

I have two populations with the same set of features. The range of the features' values is also the same.
I trained Random Forest Algorithm on the first population. Thus, I wonder whether or not I can use the model for classification of the second dataset: how can I determine whether the model is suitable for the new data?
I was thinking to compare each feature between the populations using Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test since the features aren't distributed normally. But the problem is that my datasets are huge and I received the results that all features are significantly different. So I am not sure that this is the right was to compare between the populations...
I would be happy to receive help!

Comment: When you say "two populations" do you mean "two datasets" sampled from the _same underlying population_, or 2 datasets representing one sample each from 2 populations that are expected to differ in fundamental ways? The "population" versus "sample" distinction is important here and would lead to different answers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I mean two datasets that could be or could be not sampled from the same underlying population. I assume that they do come from the same underlying population, but I don't know it for sure. So I'm trying to determine it in order to know if I can use the same model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two samples from the same population, this would be the equivalent of a training set (first sample) and a separate test set (second sample). With large numbers of cases available that is probably the best way to determine just how good your model is: how well does it work at predicting the independent separate set?

So if you know the actual class memberships of the second data sample, see how well the model from the first data sample fits the data from the second data sample, with a proper [scoring rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule) like the [Brier score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score), the equivalent of mean-square error for classification schemes. If that's not too far from what you get for the score on the first data sample, then it means that your first model was good enough to predict values from the second data sample, suggesting that the underlying populations weren't that far apart to make much of a difference.